# How to change a strings color?

Tags: android, string, colors

I want to change this string to the color red

```
String isFalse = False;
```

For some reason every tutorial seemed more complicated than I expected and I don't understand them. Is there a simple way to do this? Also, would this override the color of a textview? Because I would like it to.

Comment: I don't even have a clue what you are asking right now. Are you using a `TextView` in xml and want to set the text color?

Comment: Where actually you want to change the color of the string? post code of that layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

String is not View, so it has no color at all.

Maybe what you want is to change the appearance color of it host TextView. To achieve this you can use:

```
TextView text;
//the initialize of this TextView
text.setText(isFalse);
text.setTextColor(Color.Red);
```

The parameter of the color could be resource from your color XML values file or android.R.color resource file, or from Color class, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**string.xml**

```
<string name="isFalse"><![CDATA[<b><font color=#FF0000>False</b>]]></string>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(
            R.id.textView1);
    textView1.setText(Html.fromHtml(isFalse));
```

And result, you might get like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    String isFalse = "False";
    SpannableString redSpannable= new SpannableString(isFalse);
    redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, Tru_score.length(), 0);
    builder.append(redSpannable);


    TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text1.setText(builder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not complicated or hard
Addressing  both possibilities..
You want to change the color for your text at runtime.

that would be like [TextView.setTextColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28int%29)
i.e.

```
  falseTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red))
```

if you wanted a segment of the same textview to have a different color,by which I mean that the `isFalse` string is only  apart of the content of your TextView ,you need to use as mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29002626/3396197).